# dynamically display products in two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K5PGp/  that I am trying to modify so that it displays the "products" in two columns even if the browser is IE 8.

For example, if all 8 products are displayed, it should look like this:

### one    two

### three  four

### five   six

### seven  eight

If only 1,3,5,7 are displayed, it should look like this:

### one     three

### five    seven

If only 2,4,6,8 are displayed, it should look like this:

### two     four

### six     eight

Comment: About your fiddle, you should always try to isolate your actual issue and reduce the code to a minimum, this is common courtesy to the people that are trying to help. Your CSS is very long for example.

Comment: Another tip: HTML id attributes should always be unique (cellProductDescription in this case). A class might be more fitting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified solution

http://jsfiddle.net/w3bGj/

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` to every container. and in the each loop apply a clear function to every second element:

```
$.each(elements, function(i) {
    $product = $('<div>');
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        $product.addClass('clear');
    }
    $('div').append($product);
});
```

every second element will force a new line.

Comment: you can shorten that to `$('#container div:even').addClass("clear");`